# mongodb java client disconnect in threading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, sockets, connection

I have multi-threaded app that executes hundreds of transactions per second and after a while I start getting errors from mongo db:

I only create and use a single mongo / mongoTemplate with the following options code:

```
    private static MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
        .connectionsPerHost(1000)
        .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(15)
        .connectTimeout(60 * 1000)
        .maxWaitTime(60 * 1000)
        .socketTimeout(60 * 1000)
        .connectTimeout(60 * 1000)
        .build();
```

Here is the exception that am getting:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception opening socket; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:96)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2011)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:463)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:1034)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:974)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:920)
at com.appseleon.platform.data.repository.AbstractMongoRepository.saveWithoutIndexing(AbstractMongoRepository.java:164)
at com.appseleon.platform.corpsms.SendSMSAsyncTask.sendMsgAsyncTask(SendSMSAsyncTask.java:55)
at com.appseleon.platform.corpsms.SendSMSAsyncTask$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a955f5fa.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:46)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:362)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:93)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:80)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:69)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:184)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:177)
at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:106)
at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:58)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:747)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:730)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:327)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:323)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:314)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:284)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:250)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:172)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:392)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:367)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1039)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:461)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
... 37 more
```

Comment: If you allow 150,000 connections do you have enough file descriptors available to satisfy that? Most likely not if you haven't increased the number of fd's.

Comment: The problem happens with 10,000 too I just increased this number to see if it helps

Comment: 10,000 is probably too large too. Use `ulimit -n` to find the # of descriptors per process and on linux use `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` to find the max descriptors for the box. Edit the question so it reflects the actual situation if you would.

Comment: `ulimit -n` gives `1024` and `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives `349171` is this the reason of the error am getting? what should I do?

Comment: I changed the limits using instructions in this link [link] https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/ still I got the same error I changed the values to `fs.file-max = 500000` and `soft/hard no file 150000`

Comment: A couple of things come to mind- 1) did you verify that the new limits are what you think they are? 2) is mongodb running as the user that you upped the ulimit for?  Have you enabled thread-id output in the log? Finally, what Linux are you using? We need to know how many connections are getting run-up by the Java app and if the system can handle that number- after that we'll have to look at other things :-)

Comment: I have a cluster of 4 VMs for mongodb I made sure each one of them has the advised config and I even multiplied each value above by 10 still the same result. for the number of threads, I have around 400 threads/second each performing 2-3 transactions. any other ideas?

Comment: These next steps come to mind: 1) Enable the thread id in the log so we know how many threads are running, 2) Post all mongodb config setup from the Spring app to the question (not as a comment), 3) Increase logging for mongodb to DEBUG in the Spring app

Comment: I updated the options, now I don't get the errors anymore with the new configs (I don't use spring config to build the mongo template). But the queries are taking way too long. and the app is very slow. I even doubled the size of the master node VM but still am getting a very poor performance.

Comment: Probably time for a new question with [everything required to reproduce the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes thanks for the help